# CDF of $\max$ under conditions

Tags: probability, density-function, cumulative-distribution-function

Let,
\begin{equation}
    g(\alpha,\beta) = \begin{cases}
\frac{\alpha}{\beta}, & \text{if } \alpha > \beta \\
0, & \text{if } \alpha \leq \beta
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
I want to find the CDF of $$Z=\max\left\{g(X,Y),g(X,C)\right\}$$ where$X,Y\geq0$ are independent random variables, and $C>0$ is a constant.

I am facing two difficulties:

1. I could get the product of CDFs within $\max$ if two were
   independent. However, as they have $X$ in common, dependency is
   created. Therefore, I tried to condition on $X$ first and solve.
   However, in that case, $\frac{X}{C}$ becomes a constant, which is
   confusing me.
2. I have more complications in applying the conditions of $X>Y$ and
   $X>C$ seperately to the analysis.

Can someone help me write **the CDF of $Z$** in terms of the PDFs/CDFs of $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ independent?

Comment: @Zhanxiong - yes $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: Try to apply the cited theorem and mimic the calculation in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/606503/show-that-the-two-random-variables-with-f-distribution-are-independent/606517#606517

Comment: I don't believe that you have completely specified what $Z$ is. What is $Z$ when $X < Y$ or when $X< C$?  Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent nonnegative random variables, the event $(X < Y)$ has the same probability as the event $(X > Y)$.  So, you need to specify what $Z$ is not just (i) when $X>Y$ and $X>C$ (as you have done), but also (ii) when $X\leq Y$ and $X>C$, (iii) when $X\leq Y$ and $X\leq C$, and (iv) when $X>Y$ and $X\leq C$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate - yes you are corrcet :(. I have editted it as "$\frac{X}{Y} =0 $ when $X\le Y$; and $\frac{X}{C}=0$ when $X\le C$". Therefore, two conditions are seperetly applied for $\frac{X}{Y}$ and $\frac{X}{C} $.

Comment: Errr, no, you need better notation.  $\frac XY$ has a very specific meaning and so "$\frac XY = 0$ when $X \leq C$" is not a sensible way of writing things.  Try something like $Z = \max\big((g(X,Y), g(X,C)\big)$ where $g(\cdot,\cdot)$ is defined as $$g(\alpha,\beta) = \begin{cases} \dfrac{\alpha}{\beta}, & \alpha > \beta,\\0, &  \alpha \leq \beta.\end{cases}$$

Comment: @DilipSarwate - thanks for your suggestions - updated it accordinly.

Comment: $Z$ has a point mass in $0$, so you need to distinguish $Z=0$ from $Z>0$, the computation of $$\mathbb P(Z>0, g(X/Y)<z,g(X/C)<z)$$ depending on the cdfs of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: The CDF practically writes itself when you sketch the values of $g$ in the $(Y,X)$ plane.

Comment: @whuber can you please provide few necessary steps?

Answer (score 1):

There are six different regions (in the first quadrant of the $x$-$y$ plane) to consider depending on the values of $X, Y, C$.

- If $Y > C > X$, then $Z=\max\left\{g(X,Y),g(X,C)\right\} = \max\left\{0, 0 \right\} = 0.$
- If $Y > X > C$, then $Z=\max\left\{g(X,Y),g(X,C)\right\} = \max\left\{0, \frac XC \right\} = \frac XC.$
- If $X > Y > C$, then $Z=\max\left\{g(X,Y),g(X,C)\right\} = \max\left\{\frac XY, \frac XC \right\} = \frac XC.$
- If $X > C > Y$, then $Z=\max\left\{g(X,Y),g(X,C)\right\} = \max\left\{\frac XY, \frac XC \right\} = \frac XY.$
- If $C > X > Y$, then $Z=\max\left\{g(X,Y),g(X,C)\right\} = \max\left\{\frac XY, 0 \right\} = \frac XY.$
- If $C > Y > X$, then $Z=\max\left\{g(X,Y),g(X,C)\right\} = \max\left\{0,0 \right\} = 0.$

Can you take it from here?